# Why is .map() not a function when using Array.prototype.slice.call()?

Tags: javascript

`.map()` on arrays expects a function as parameter. This works:

```
[[1]].map(function(array) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(array);
});
```

`typeof Array.prototype.slice.call` returns `"function"`.

**So why doesn't the following call work?**

```
[[1]].map(Array.prototype.slice.call);
```

It throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: [[1]].map is not a function
    at Array.map (native)
    at <anonymous>:2:7
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Comment: Issuing .call against a function does not return you function.  It invokes the function with a specified value of 'this'.

Comment: If I call a variable with `()`, it is a function to me. `typeof` also returns `"function"`. This also does not explain the error message.